# How to refresh only a image of a whole page, when the imagename is variabel?

Tags: image, load, refresh, onload

This is my puzzle i'm struggeling with:

I have a website with a certain amount of images, and i'd like the images to be refreshed each say 20 seconds,

this is the code I wrote so far for that:

```
<IMG src="imgcam/mostasquare_1.jpg" border="1" name="refresh" id="img1">
<IMG src="imgcam/mriehelbypass_1.jpg" border="1" name="refresh" id="img2">

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var t = 35 // Interval in Seconds
images = new Array('../imgcam/mostasquare_1.jpg','../imgcam/mriehelbypass_1.jpg'); //URLs of the Images

function Start() {
tmp = new Date();
tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime();
for (i=1;i<image.length;i++){
document.getElementById("img"+i).src = images[i]+tmp;
}
setTimeout("Start()", t*1000)
}
Start();
</SCRIPT>
```

And solely this works great, 
But, here is the catch:

I also would like to force the browser to refresh/download all images when opening the page.

so therefor I appended a querystring with a random number (or time, or version, etc).

so that resulted in:

```
<img src="mostasquare_1.jpg80123123" alt="image1" />
```

However, 
*because* I added the random number, the **array** has got the wrong values

how can I tackle this specific "catch22" problem?

bonus points: i'd also like to show a little text on top of the image(s) (floating with css or so?) which shows when the last refresh of the image took place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find an example using jquery: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waGbQg

You can keep original path inside a data-attribute and update src starting from it in this way:

```
$this.attr("src", $this.attr("data-original-image") + "?" + d.getTime());
```